# Warnigns javascript en console

Tags: javascript, html5, web, dom, plugin

Estoy tratando de cargar un plugin en mi web pero no me lo esta cargando correctamente
Me esta tirando algunos errores y warnings que no se bien como solucionarlo

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que se trata?
Algun consejo para solucionarlo?

Dejo una captura dela consola con los warnings
El plugin es jquery-circle-progress[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<td class="light">
   <div class="circulito" data-value="<?= round($porc['porc'],1) ?>" >
                                                    
   </div>
 </td>

<script src="/webroot/plugins/circle/dist/circle-progress.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.circulito').circleProgress({
        size: 50,
        startAngle: 11,
        lineCap: 'round',
        fill: {
            color: "#44aaf2"
        }
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
        $(this).find('strong').text(stepValue.toFixed(2));
        // $(this).find('strong').html(Math.round(100 * progress) + '<i>%</i>');
    });

    

</script>
```

Comment: Hola! Seria bueno que pusieras el código con el que llamas el plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente no cargabas bien la librería: Sea por que no encuentra el archivo o no tenga permisos el servidor web envía un error en forma de página html, si no incluye las cabeceras de error el navegador carga ese html como si fuera el script ( de ahí que el warning sea que no coincide el tipo mime ). Como no puedo acceder a tu sistema de directorios he cargado la librería a través de un **CDN**. También te faltaba añadirle un `value:` al objeto para que se lance el renderizado.

En el ejemplo que nos pones <s>no cargabas tampoco la librería **Jquery** pero supongo que en tu proyecto si que lo hacías</s>. Al fallar la carga del script del plugin, `circleProgress` ya no es una función.

Aquí puedes ver el código funcionando:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/circle-progress.js"></script>


<div class="circulito" data-value="5"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.circulito').circleProgress({
        size: 50,
        value: 0.75,
        startAngle: 11,
        lineCap: 'round',
        fill: {
            color: "#44aaf2"
        }
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
        $(this).find('strong').text(stepValue.toFixed(2));
        // $(this).find('strong').html(Math.round(100 * progress) + '<i>%</i>');
    });
    

</script>
```

**Anotación:** He quitado el **PHP** de tu código para poder hacer que se reproduzca aquí.

**Referencia:** [Documentación del plugin](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress)

Comment: Perfecto!! Me funciono gracias!!